# Unable to post data to mongoDb atlas using router

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb

When I am trying to post data using `Router.post` method from my express server to MongoDB atlas it is showing me **`users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms**.
It is taking too much time in processing and after processing showing this.

[image: this is my CreateUser code through which i am trying to post data]

[image: this is my expree main index.js file]

[image: this is my schema file]

My database is connected to mongoose atlas and I am able to get data through it, also when I'm trying `router.get` method that is working properly.

Comment: please put the code instead here rather then using image

Comment: sure i'll ,  thnx for suggestion